# static files with gunicorn, django and nginx

Tags: django, nginx, hosts, gunicorn, static-files

I have a django project and want to deploy it using gunicorn and nginx.

So far everything works, but when I add subdomains, static files are not served and my page look terrible!

If I use localhosts instead, everything works perfect!

Here I leave my nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80 default;
    client_max_body_size 4G; 
    server_name mytest.dev;

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    # path for static files
    root /Users/danielrodriguez/workspace/mtt/static;

    location / { 
        # checks for static file, if not found proxy to app 
        try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }   

    location @proxy_to_app {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_pass   http://localhost:8000;
    }   
}
```

I also have this in my hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   mytest.dev
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
```

How can I make nginx to work as it does when I type "localhost" in my browser when I type "mydev.test"? Pretty much all I want to do is serve a bunch of sites within the same physical server using something like virtualhosts in apache.

PD: I'm also using OS Lion in case it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**That seems you have wrong `root` setting.**

```
root /Users/danielrodriguez/workspace/mtt/static;
```

You should check the requested URL for your css files. Assumimg you have `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` you're browser will probably want to load `/static/css/styles.css` or something like that.

So, the file `./static/css/styles.css` should be found in `root` directory.

**Then right `root` should be:**

```
root /Users/danielrodriguez/workspace/mtt;
```

Of course that's really not good idea to make `root` setting to your project root. So' you may create symlink for `static` and `media` to separate dir outside your project.

Hope that helps.